# wkb: could not create geometry because of errors while reading input

Tags: python-3.x, csv, shapely

I am trying to translate ewkb coordinates into the associated longitude and latitude on Python. The ewkb strings are listed in a one-column csv file (named "/home/nick/Documents/Sepi/WKB_coordinates_sing.csv").

I deleted the other columns for the sake of simplicity, but eventually I would like to use the original data set and read just the right column with ewkb.

Moreover, I would like to read and translate one line at a time, because I have files with millions of lines and coordinates to process.

I wrote the following code:

```
from shapely import wkb
with open ("/home/nick/Documents/Sepi/WKB_coordinates_sing.csv") as f:
    for line in f:
        hexloc=f.readline()
        print(hexloc)
        point=wkb.loads(hexloc,hex=True)
        print(point.x,point.y)
```

However, when I run it, I get the following:

```
~$ python /home/nick/Documents/Sepi/ewkb.py
0101000020E610000072604C0D47AA37402C306475ABA85140
ParseException: Premature end of HEX string
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nick/Documents/Sepi/ewkb.py", line 7, in <module>
    point=wkb.loads(hexloc,hex=True)
  File "/home/nick/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/shapely/wkb.py", line 14, in loads
    return reader.read_hex(data)
  File "/home/nick/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/shapely/geos.py", line 409, in read_hex
    "Could not create geometry because of errors "
shapely.errors.WKBReadingError: Could not create geometry because of errors while reading input.
```

However, I can obtain longitude and latitude if I run the following code with the first hexadecimal string from my csv file as argument of wkb.loads:

Code:

```
from shapely import wkb
hexloc="0101000020E610000072604C0D47AA37402C306475ABA85140"
print(hexloc)
point=wkb.loads(hexloc,hex=True)
print(point.x,point.y)
```

Result:

```
~$ python /home/nick/Documents/Sepi/ewkb.py
0101000020E610000072604C0D47AA37402C306475ABA85140
23.665146666666665 70.63546500000001
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be several possible issues. First, your code snippet is mixing iteration and direct "read" methods. With this example:

```
with open ("/home/nick/Documents/Sepi/WKB_coordinates_sing.csv") as f:
    for line in f:
        hexloc=f.readline()
        #do something with hexloc
```

`hexloc` will effectively iterate only over every second line in the input file. You might want to replace this with:

```
with open ("/home/nick/Documents/Sepi/WKB_coordinates_sing.csv") as f:
    for hexloc in f:
        #do something with hexloc
```

Moreover, when you read the input lines like this, they retain the trailing newline which confuses the `loads` method. I would suggest to try:

```
with open ("/home/nick/Documents/Sepi/WKB_coordinates_sing.csv") as f:
    for line in f:
        hexloc = line.strip()
        point = wkb.loads(hexloc, hex=True)
```